# Query generated have empty field

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I use spring-data-jpa with hibernate implemetation.

I have a bail who contain a list of rent.

```
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "bail")
    private List<Rent> rents;
```

A rent can have many payment.

```
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "rent")
    @OrderBy
    private List<RoomPayment> roomPaymentList;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bail_id")
    private Bail bail;
```

So i try to get rent who have incomplete payment or no payment

```
select r from Rent r Join r.bail.lodger l where r.unpaidBalance > 0 or r.roomPaymentList is null order by r.rentId
```

Hibernate converts this query to

```
select
        rent0_.rent_id as rent_id1_33_,
        rent0_.bail_id as bail_id5_33_,
        rent0_.from_date as from_dat2_33_,
        rent0_.to_date as to_date3_33_,
        rent0_.unpaid_balance as unpaid_b4_33_ 
    from
        rent rent0_ 
    inner join
        bail bail1_ 
            on rent0_.bail_id=bail1_.bail_id 
    inner join
        lodger lodger2_ 
            on bail1_.lodger_id=lodger2_.lodger_id cross 
    join
        room_payment roompaymen3_ 
    where
        rent0_.rent_id=roompaymen3_.rent_id 
        and (
            rent0_.unpaid_balance>0 
            or . is null
        ) 
    order by
        rent0_.rent_id
```

or is null... something is missing there

Comment: Like i wrote, i use spring-data-jpa with hibernate implemetation

Answer (score 0):

A list can't be null. It can be empty though:

```
or r.roomPaymentList is empty
```